# Converting user word input into price

Tags: python

I am having a ton of trouble with my program. I have looked everywhere for the past 5 hours and cannot seem to find anything that is relevant to what I am trying to do (that I can understand anyways).

I am creating a pizza program and trying to get an input for size (such as large, medium, small). The program will ask the user to type in large, medium, or small, and the price to a blank list.

I have set the price, but I am utterly confused about how I need to convert the large,medium,small input into the actual price I've set for that size.

Here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated. I also semi understand that I should not use int for pricing, but all of the commands I've looked up are for an older version of Python or something.

Currently using Python 3.5.

```
print ("Welcome to My Pizzeria!")
name = input("What name is the order under? ")
size = input("What size would you like? ")
top = input("Would you like to add sausage? ")
money = 0
total = (size+top)
if size == 'large':
   total = int(money) + 10.00
elif size == 'medium':
  total = int(money) + 7.00
elif size == 'small':
  total = int(money) + 5.00
money = total
if top == 'no':
  total = int(money) + 0.00
elif top == 'yes':
  total = int(money) + 1.00
  pass
print ("Your total is $" + str(total))
print ("Thank you for your order " + name + "!")
```

Comment: What is `money`, is it the base price? becoz in your case it is set to `None` which is incorrect. IMO it should be some fixed integer value OR you may want to take this input from user

Comment: Money was just me trying to test some ideas. I have updated with the code I am toying with at the moment. I have to later make my program loop if more pizzas are desired. Basically all I am asking is how can I make a pseudo "if" statement. Like: if answer to "what size do you want" is large then add 10.00 to total

Answer (score 0):

In that case I think this is what you want.
I have filled money with pseudo value of 10, though I have still wrapped it in int in case you have it in str format.

```
print ("Welcome to My Pizzeria!")
name = input("What name is the order under? ")
size = input("What size would you like? ").lower()
top = input("Would you like to add sausage? ").lower()
money = 0
if size == 'large':
   total = int(money) + 10.00
elif size == 'medium':
  total = int(money) + 7.00
elif size == 'small':
  total = int(money) + 5.00
money = total
if top == 'no':
  total = int(money) + 0.00
elif top == 'yes':
  total = int(money) + 1.00
print ("Your total is $" + str(total))
print ("Thank you for your order " + name + "!")
```

**OP**

```
Welcome to My Pizzeria!
What name is the order under?  Saurabh
What size would you like?  Large
Would you like to add sausage?  Yes
Your total is $11.0
Thank you for your order Saurabh!
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really do appreciate your help. I added a few lines to your code and I am about to try and add a looping statement. Updated the original post with new code.

Answer (score 0):

This code will ask for the users answer until they provide a valid answer, then break the infinite loop and go onto the next one. You do not need the variable "money", as the total can be added to throughout the script without the need for extra variables. 'x += 1' is just short for 'x = x+1'. Hope this helps!

```
print ("Welcome to My Pizzeria!")
name = input("What name is the order under? ")
total = 0

while 1:
    size = input("What size would you like? ").lower()
    if size == 'large':
        total += 10.00
        break
    elif size == 'medium':
        total += 7.00
        break
    elif size == 'small':
        total += 5.00
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, that is not an option! Please order something else!")

while 1:
    top = input("Would you like to add sausage? ").lower
    if top == 'no':
        total += 0.00
        break
    elif top == 'yes':
        total += 1.00
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, that is not an option! Please order something else!")

print ("Your total is $" + str(total))
print ("Thank you for your order " + name + "!")
```